# Поиск по таблице mysql php

Tags: php, mysql

Как сделать запрос, чтобы срабатывала фильтрация по дате?

```
SELECT * 
FROM modxev_programm_oner
WHERE  `user_id` =18
OR parent =18
AND  `datao` =  '2018-07-16'
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: В полном виде укажите дату в выборке.

Comment: Укажите скобками порядок выполнения логических операторов. OR имеет приоритет меньше, чем AND.

Comment: про скобки не понял, подскажите пожалуйста

Comment: если глянуть на дату, то or не должен выводиться, а он выводитсяъ

Answer (score 0):

Если нужно выводить совпадение user_id + дата ИЛИ parent + дата тогда так:

```
SELECT * 
FROM modxev_programm_oner
WHERE  (`user_id` = 18 OR `parent` = 18)
AND  `datao` =  '2018-07-16'
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

Если user_id ИЛИ parent + дата тогда так:

```
SELECT * 
FROM modxev_programm_oner
WHERE  `user_id` = 18
OR (`parent` = 18 AND  `datao` =  '2018-07-16')
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

и наверное лучше привести поле к типу даты DATE(datao) = '2018-07-16'